# C++0x threads give no speed up

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, future

I've written a program for search of the maximum in arrays using c++0x threads (for learning purposes). For implementation I used standard *thread* and *future* classes. However, parallelized function constantly showes same or worse run time than non-parallelized.

Code is below. I tried to store data in one-dimensional array, multi-dimensional array and ended up with several arrays. However, no option has given good results. I tried to compile and run my code from Eclipse and command line, still with no success. I also tried similar test without array usage. Parallelization gave only 20% speed up there. From my point of view, I run very simple parallel program, without locks and almost no resource sharing (each thread operates on his own array). What is bottleneck?

My machine has Intel Core i7 processor 2.2 GHz with 8 GB of RAM, running Ubuntu 12.04.

```
const int n = 100000000;

int a[n], b[n], c[n], d[n];

int find_max_usual() {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        res = max(res, a[i]);
        res = max(res, b[i]);
        res = max(res, c[i]);
        res = max(res, d[i]);
    }
    return res;
}

int find_max(int *a) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        res = max(res, a[i]);
    return res;
}

int find_max_parallel() {
    future<int> res_a = async(launch::async, find_max, a);
    future<int> res_b = async(launch::async, find_max, b);
    future<int> res_c = async(launch::async, find_max, c);
    future<int> res_d = async(launch::async, find_max, d);
    int res = max(max(res_a.get(), res_b.get()), max(res_c.get(), res_d.get()));
    return res;
}

double get_time() {
    timeval tim;
    gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
    double t = tim.tv_sec + (tim.tv_usec / 1000000.0);
    return t;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = rand();
        b[i] = rand();
        c[i] = rand();
        d[i] = rand();
    }
    double start = get_time();
    int x = find_max_usual();
    cerr << x << " " << get_time() - start << endl;
    start = get_time();
    x = find_max_parallel();
    cerr << x << " " << get_time() - start << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Timing showed that almost all the time in find_max_parralel is consumed by

```
int res = max(max(res_a.get(), res_b.get()), max(res_c.get(), res_d.get()));
```

Compilation command line

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++0x -pthread x.cpp
```

**Update.** Problem is solved. I got desired results with same test. 4 threads give about 3.3 speed up, 3 threads give about 2.5 speed up, 2 threads behave almost ideally with 1.9 speed up. I've just rebooted system with some new updates. I haven't seen any significant difference in cpu load and running porgrams.

Thanks to all for help.

Comment: Unfortunately, `std::future` and company are new enough that most vendors are primarily concerned with just getting them to work. Most have not yet had the benefit of a great deal of fine tuning.

Comment: `clock()` measures the consumed CPU time, not the elapsed wall-clock time. It is perfectly normal to get more CPU time with more threads :)

Comment: The problem is that clock() constantly shows same or more time for parallelized function.

Comment: This is what _is supposed to happen_ - threading adds overhead and it takes more _CPU time_ to complete the work. Use `gettimeofday()` or some other clocking function to measure the _wall-clock (real) time_, not the CPU time. Besides your problem is memory-bound and you should not expect much of an improvement with many threads.

Comment: gettimeofday() just lead to similar results(

Comment: @Andrii You won't get any speed up, there is just not enough computation in this example. If you change the errors I pointed out, you program is acting multi-threaded. Read my explanation to your screenshot.

Comment: I also tried similar test without array usage (with functions). Parallelization gave only 20% speed up there.

Comment: @bamboon I still can't understand, what is bottleneck here. Calculations take about 0.5 sec which is not negligible.

Comment: @Andrii I just tested it and I even got a speed up of >2. All the basic reasons have been mentioned. Please revert your question-text to your original state such that it represents the actual question and answer. Everything else doesn't belong in this question

Comment: What is "Parallelization gave only 20% speed up there." suppose to mean? Why were you expecting something different? It sounds like you think multithreading is just something you throw at some code to make it magically 100% faster. It has overhead in itself, and you need to consider shared state, synchronization, etc. It's not something you can do without knowing what you're getting in to.

Comment: @GManNickG C++ thread's creators should have implemented good library. My code doesn't have locks. Version with functions (using value a * i + b instead of a[i]) use constant memory. So, in theory, here should be mimimal overhead related to synchronization, shared resources etc.

Is here any way to get about 4x speed up?

Comment: GManNickG Well, I just haven't expected that multithreading is SO unefficient. Is here any way to do this better?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to explicitly set `std::launch::async`.

```
future<int> res_c = async(std::launch::async, find_max, c);
```

If you omit the flag `std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred` is assumend which leaves it up to implementation to choose whether to start the task asynchronously or deferred.

Current versions of gcc use `std::launch::deferred`, MSVC has an runtime scheduler which decides on runtime how the task should be run.

Also note that if you want to try:

```
std::async(find_max, c);
```

this will also block because the destructor of `std::future` waits for the task to finish.

Comment: std::async(find_max, c)   shouldn't block, but   res_a.get() should.

Comment: Timing shows that almost all the time is consumed by line 

"int res = max(max(res_a.get(), res_b.get()), max(res_c.get(), res_d.get()));"

Comment: @Andrii It works ;), the problem is that the actual computation time of your program is spend in your calls to `rand()`, which are only singlethreaded. Open your task manager and you will see usage spikes on all cores. `std::async` called without storing the future blocks because it creates a temporary future, which gets destroyed after the call to async and the destructor of the future is blocking.

Comment: I calculated only time used for function calls, 'start' variable's assignment goes after random calls.

Comment: On my machine usage spikes only on one core... I have enough reputation now, so I'll post the image.

Comment: @Andrii Your screenshot shows, that the most time is being used allocating RAM(see the rising RAM usage), then when the RAM bar doesn't change anymore but CPU is still at 100%, that's the interval where the `rand`calls are, the computation of the  max calls is so short that they don't spike 100% in task manager, in addition you have a 8 threads, such that only half of them at max are used. Parallelization doesn't show any benefits in small computation times, it even adds more overhead.

Comment: However, max search itself doesn't spike cpu usage a lot. I added sleep after numbers' generation.

Comment: @Andrii Since you're using C++11 you can abandon `rand()` for usage of the standard `<random>` library, which can be parallelized, gives you better control over run-time characteristics, and is generally a huge improvement over `rand()`.

Comment: I changed timing function to gettimeofday(). Results are the same: parallel function uses slightly more time than non-parallel. I even tried to repeat loops to increase running time. Optimizer didn't broke it, but results are still same.

Comment: @Andrii and you can also use the standard `<chrono>` library instead of `gettimeofday()`. `<chrono>` typesafe, works with any duration, multiple representations, is part of the standard lib, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran the same test with gcc-4.7.1 and threaded version is roughly 4 times faster (on 4-core server).
So the problem is obviously not in std::future implementation, but in choosing threading settings not optimal for your environment. As it was noted above, you test is not CPU, but memory intensive, so the bottleneck is definitely memory access. 
You'd probably want to run some cpu-intensive test (like computing PI number with high precision) to benchmark threading properly.

Without experimenting with different number of threads and different array sizes, it's hard to say, where exactly the bottleneck is, but there are probably few things in play:
 - You probably have 2-channel memory controller (it's either 2, or 3), so going above 2 threads will just introduce additional contention around memory access. Thus your thesis about having no locking and no resource sharing is not correct: on hardware level there's contention around concurrent memory access.
 - Non-parallel version will be efficiently optimized by pre-fetching data into cache. On other hand, there's chance, that in parallel version you end up with intensive context switching, and as result thrashing CPU cache.

For both factors you are likely to see a speedup, if you tune down number of threads to 2.